# Angular, onLoad function on an iFrame

Tags: iframe, angularjs

I have this iframe working with basic JavaScript:

```
<iframe id="upload_iframe" name="upload_iframe" onLoad="uploadDone();"></iframe>
```

Which triggers the method `uploadDone();` when the content of the iframe has been loaded.

How do I do the same thing in Angular?. I want to call a function on the controller when the iframe loads, but I haven't seen a `ng-onload` so far.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try defining the function within controller as:

```
window.uploadDone=function(){
  /* have access to $scope here*/
}
```

Comment: is there an option to pass angular params as well? such as
`code`
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<iframe src="{{item.url}}" onload="iframeLoaded(item)" />

Comment: The downside to this is that it mixes a global function with Angular code. It works, but it could be confusing. Eg. "Would someone else reading the code expect to find it in the controller? Will it conflict with anything else?"

Answer (score 121):

Commenting on a year old question.
For cases where there are more than 1 iframes, I needed to bind "onload" events on to.
I did this approach.

Directive

```
APP.directive('iframeOnload', [function(){
return {
    scope: {
        callBack: '&iframeOnload'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('load', function(){
            return scope.callBack();
        })
    }
}}])
```

Controller

```
APP.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.iframeLoadedCallBack = function(){
        // do stuff
    }
}]);
```

DOM

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <iframe iframe-onload="iframeLoadedCallBack()" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this directive. I changed the callback call in the directive by : `return scope.callBack(element);` so I can read element attributes back in my function.

Comment: Hmm or you could even return it as a promise!

Comment: I went on and edited the scope hash as you suggested. @Pandaiolo

Comment: I tried to pass element but was not accessible , is there a small working demo that you can share?

Comment: Make sure your call back is a function,
    iframe-onload="iframeLoadedCallBack()"

Make sure your call back accepts a parameter
    $scope.iframeLoadedCallBack = function(element) {...}

Comment: Miguel, your solution works great! But, please, for the people who copy-paste code, unhook the event handler on destroy:     `scope.$on('$destroy', function() { element.off('load'); })`

Answer (score 35):

For anyone using Angular 2+,
It's simply:

```
<iframe (load)="uploadDone()"></iframe>
```

No global function, works with multiple iframe.

Comment: @hajjin How I show loader until the uploadDone completes

Comment: You can have a variable showLoader, and display the loader based on it's value. Set it to true after loading start. and set it to false inside uploadDone.

Comment: This is definetely the right answer in an angular context.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone ending up here, the [ng-onload](https://github.com/mikaturunen/ng-onload) plugin is the perfect solution to this issue. It doesn't pollute the global namespace and doesn't require you to create one-off directives when all you want is to call a simple scope function.

Comment: ngOnload only appears to return undefined with respect to the contentWindow for Angular 1.5.x.  Have you used it on this version of AngularJS and had it work?

Answer (score 1):

for those that inject the iframe dynamically, you could do the following

html...

```
<div #iframeContainer></div>
```

ts...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-iframe-onload',
  templateUrl: './iframe-onload.component.html'
})
export class IframeOnload implements AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild('iframeContainer') iframeContainer: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.injectIframe();
}

private injectIframe(): void {
  const container = this.iframeContainer.nativeElement;
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
  iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://example.com/');
  iframe.setAttribute('height', 'auto');
  iframe.setAttribute('frameBorder', '0');
  iframe.addEventListener('load', this.iframeOnLoadtwo);
  container.appendChild(iframe);

}

public iframeOnLoadtwo(): void {
  console.log('iframe loaded...');
}

}
```