# How to wireup an AngularStrap modal show event

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, angular-strap

I have the modal displaying just fine. I'm trying to figure out how to run a function when the modal is shown.

```
 var = loginModal = $modal({ placement: 'left', title: '', content: webauth, show: false });

 $scope.$on('modal.show', function () {
        console.log("SHOWN");
        debugger;
    });

    $scope.showModal = function () {

        loginModal.$promise
            .then(loginModal.show);

    };
```

I was expecting the $scope.$on('modal.show') to fire when the modal is shown, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.showModal = function() {
    myModal.$promise.then(myModal.show).then(function(){
        console.info('shown');
    });
};
```

Comment: That works. My issue now which I didn't foresee is that the content of the modal is an Iframe and is not immediately available when the event fires. I have some ideas on that. Thanks much for your help!

Comment: In case anyone is interested I used this post to wire up the iframe onload event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882326/angular-onload-function-on-an-iframe:                        window.uploadDone=function(){
  /* have access to $scope here*/
}