# How to delay modal iframe until full data load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

Is it possible to show a `modal` window only if embedded `iframe` is fully loaded (an embedded `pdf`)?

```
//triggered by frontend
$scope.onmodal = function() {
    $scope.url = "dynamic generated url";
    $('#myModal').modal({
        show: true, //how to delay?
        backdrop: true
    });
};
```

My html:
Trigger Modal in iFrame

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="position:inherit !important;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">PDF View</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe ng-src="{{url}}" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to trigger the modal popup on button click, but delay it until the embedded url (a pdf) has been fully loaded.
Because the pdf is generated in the backend, and a long running process (10 sec).

Is it possible?

Comment: Try using ONLOAD `<iframe onload="onIframeLoaded();">`  or `document.getElementById("myFrame").onload = function() { ... };` to change modal show to true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular, onLoad function on an iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882326/angular-onload-function-on-an-iframe)