# Load event of dynamic iframe in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, iframe

I have an angular directive that uses an iframe to download a file.  I want to be able to detect when that iframe is loaded, but the event isn't firing.

```
        var iframe = angular.element('<iframe></iframe>');
        iframe.on("load", function() { console.log("loaded"); });
        iframe.attr('src', url);
        iframe.css('display', 'none');

        angular.element(document.body).append(iframe);
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23948165/1887101

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the same question.

Comment: Your code works for me [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YVc8O07Q8OZ33Bsdkv7b). Make sure URL is correct and doesn't refuse to be loaded in an iframe

Comment: Hmmm, that might be the key.  The url is working.  But like I mentioned, it's to download a file.  Specifically an excel file.  So the content type and disposition may be playing games with the event handler.

Comment: Do you have a URL to such a file that you can share without security threat? In  this case update the plunker to create an MCVE

Comment: Hmmm, nope.  But let me see if I can find a comparable link online.

Comment: I think with AngularJS you should engage different approaches, for example [simple anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670754/angularjs-simple-file-download)