# is angular1.x directive compile stage's element.ready the equivalent of javascript's onload for an elment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onload, onload-event, ready

I want to specifically use element.`onload(function(){})` for when the element is completedly loaded in `compile`'s `post`step. But I saw the `elem` inside compile include `onload` as `null` so basically `onload` does not exist for angular element. I found .`ready` attached to the element function though, but is this equivalent?

My scenario:
Basically I have a directive contains google ad, and I include it with another directive using ng-transclude, that, transclude the google ad directive into it.

I want to see if there is a way to determine exact moment when the ad is completely loaded, I thought `onload` for the dom is a good option, but I can't find that equivalent inside angular directive's elem argument in compile stage, which supposedly the stage where all dom should be rendered?

Comment: Don't think so. Angularjs is SPA (single page application), and it loads views (I.E other HTMLs) when you navigate from one state to another so the DOM can always be `ready` and `load`ed, that's why you need to be more specific about why you need this in the first place (Pretty sure there is  a pure angular solution for what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: @AlonEitan added my scenario

Comment: Would [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23948165/754119) be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to go :

```
var $scope.init = function(){
 //your code`enter code here`
}
```